# Question about references

Tags: c++

I think the following is really basic but I don't really get what would be the "advantages" of one of these code.

Having this:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    f(a);
    return 0;
}
```

What would be the difference between

```
void f(int& a)
{
    int& b = a;
}
```

and

```
void f(int& a)
{
    int b = a;
}
```

In particular, in the case where `f` would instead be the constructor of a class and where instead of an `int` we have a big object.

I would go with the second possibility... What do you think ?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

First, looking at the answers, I though I was brain dead when I posted the question, but actually I found interesting subquestions (and answers !) in the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First:

```
void f(int& a) {
    int& b = a;
}
```

The caller passes in an `a`, which we get as a reference to the caller's `a`. Then we create a new referece `b` which refers to `a`, which is still the caller's `a`. As a result, any changes the caller makes will be visible to `f` and its containing class, and any changes made in `f` to either `a` or `b` will affect what the caller passed in as `a`.

```
void f(int& a) {
    int b = a;
}
```

Here, `b` is a new variable, an `int`, which takes a *copy* of `a`. Changes made to `b` won't affect the caller, nor will the caller affect `b`. But a quicker way of writing the same thing is:

```
void f(int b) {
}
```

and dispense with the `a` reference entirely. In particular, this shows in the prototype that the function will not modify its parameter, because it cannot; while a prototype of `void f (int &a)` indicates that it *may* modify `a`.

Edit: if you need to avoid any copying, a Third Option (tm) is a reference to const:

```
void f(const int &a) {
    const int &b = a;
}
```

inside `f`, neither `a` nor `b` can be modified, so it can't affect the caller, but copying is avoided by using a reference to const. There is still a potential problem that any changes to `a` caused by the caller will be visible inside the object, because there is only one actual data item `a` and many names for it; that's something you'd have to document to ensure the caller does not do any such thing.

Comment: Thanks ! So to construct a class without any copy I would have to have a member which is a reference, and the constructor have to accept a reference as a parameter also ?

Comment: +1: I would prefer the term "reference to const' instead of 'const reference'.

Comment: @chubsdad: fair point. 'const reference' is not nearly as bad as 'const pointer' though.

Comment: References are always constant, right ? They cannot be "reassignated" to something else after initialization ?

Comment: @Cedric: references are always constant, but the thing they refer to can be const or not.

Answer (score 4):

`int& b = a` does not copy a, `int b = a` does.

Most importantly, the caller of your constructor can change the object and you will see those changes in your new object. Even worse: If the caller destroys the object (or it is automatically destroyed), your object has an invalid reference.

Comment: So `f(int a) { int& b=a;)` and `f(int& a) {int b = a;}` would be equivallent ? In term of copy.

Comment: @Cedric H.: In the first case 'int &b - a', reference is being created to a stack local variable namely the formal parameter 'a'. It is very dangerous in case you want to return back any reference from the function

Answer (score 2):

The second version creates a copy of the variable while the first one only generates another reference to the original object. If you just have a reference, Bad Things (tm) will happen if the caller destroys his object. So you most likely want to go with the second version (unless you can be sure using a reference is safe).

Comment: But if I need to avoid any copy, I would have to do `f(int& a) { int& b =a;}` or `f(int* a) {int* b = a;}` (and call `f(&a)` in the second case) ?